# How to convert pixel values in excel file into an image?

Tags: python, excel, image, csv

I have an Excel file, with 100 rows and 100 columns. Each element is a pixel intensity value. How can I convert it into a 2D grayscale image using Python?

Comment: Excel file as in having an `.xlsx` extension?

Comment: Please share your Excel file - preferably as a CSV. If you really mean a `.xlsx` file, you'll need to use Dropbox or Google Drive or similar.

Comment: you can use `pandas` or other module to read excel file. And later you have to write code to convert it to `numpy array` which you can save as image using `opencv` or you can convert `numpy array` to `pillow.Image`. If you use `csv` files then you my try to read it directly as `numpy array` using [numpy.loadtxt](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html)

Comment: If you have a CSV, formatted exactly as in Martin's answer, you don't need to write any Python, you can use `vips` on the command-line to make a PNG like this `vips im_csv2vips image.csv result.png`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have an Excel `.xlsx` file you could use [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) to read in the values. The [Pillow](https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/) library can be used to build and save the image.

Assuming each value is an 8-bit value, the following approach could be used:

```
from itertools import chain
from PIL import Image
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("image.xlsx")
ws = wb.active
data = list(ws.iter_rows(values_only=True))

rows = len(data)
cols = max(len(row) for row in data)

img = Image.new('L', (cols, rows), color='black')
img.putdata(list(chain.from_iterable(data)))
img.save('output.png')
```

So for an Excel file containing these values:

[image: Excel screenshot]

You would get a PNG image looking like (enlarged):

[image: png image]

---

If your file is actually in CSV format:

```
from itertools import chain
from PIL import Image
import csv

data = []

with open('image.csv', newline='') as f_input:
    for row in csv.reader(f_input):
        data.append(list(map(int, row)))
        
rows = len(data)
cols = max(len(row) for row in data)

img = Image.new('L', (cols, rows), color='black')
img.putdata(list(chain.from_iterable(data)))
img.save('output.png')
```

e.g. `image.csv` contains:

```
24,1,4,255,43,2
2,4,6,0,3,2
1,1,255,3,32,5
```